# How to avoid circular reference OOAD design

Tags: oop

I have Class structure like below, this below scenario will create a cyclic reference.  How to avoid this situation?

```
public class classA
{
    public classA()
    {
        classB b= new classB();
        b.classBMethod();
    }
    public void classAMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class A Method");
    }
}
public class classB
{
    public classB()
    {
        classC c = new classC();
        c.classCMethod();
    }
    public void classBMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class B Method");
    }
}
public class classC
{
    public classC()
    {
        classA a = new classA();
        a.classAMethod();
    }
    public void classCMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class C Method");
    }
}
```

> How to avoid circular reference? Please tell me different alternatives to design this

Answer (score 5):

Your code does not have a circular reference problem.
Circular reference occurs when you start following references and end up where you started. In your case, what you do is declaring local variables and then you have:

```
new ClassA()-> (calls) -> new ClassB()->(calls)->new ClassC()->calls->new ClassA()-> (calls) -> new ClassB()->(calls)-> etc forever
```

The GC is smart enough to resolve circular references, but what you are doing is fundamentally flawed. Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to achieve instead.

Comment: In the above case, it leads to stack overflow exception. The above code creates a circular reference. If you execute the code you can find the problem. I wanted to know how we can resolve such cyclic refernce?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that this will blow up? I mentioned what a circular reference is.In your case you don't have that.Your code is flawed. Why don't you mention what you are trying to do, so that we help you there

Answer (score 2):

This is creating a spiral data-structure to which there is no end.
However, the simplest way to solve this riddle and still be able to start with any class (A,B, or C), is to add a public boolean flag to the objects that determines if a cycle has occurred. If this flag is false you continue, if it is true you stop the cycle. If instead you are trying to create this spiral with no end, you may need to add an update method called once per frame to avoid an overload of operations in an instance.

I could give a less vague answer if I knew exactly what you were trying to create with this type of logic. I'm sorry if this was unclear.

Comment: Hi Joseph, your answer seems to be fine. My intention is to learn how to overcome such issue in real time environment. Thanks for your reply.